# to create client.jar file in ejb in addition to myEJB.jar file

Tags: eclipse, ejb, glassfish-3

I am using Eclipse to create an EJB project. But when I export the whole EJB project `client.jar` file for remote stateless beans is not getting created, just `myEJB.jar` is created.

How to create `client.jar` file on Eclipse?

I am using Glassfish server to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe go to project->properties->deployment assembly and add the jar to the project you want to deploy